Looking for a function to reduce extreme probability predictions from a low sample
I'm trying to do some gambling predictions for racers based on their previous times with low sample sizes. The problem is that due to low sample size, I can get extreme probabilities which I know can't really be correct. For example, let's say there are 2 racers, each having a vector of times (lower is better, vectors don't have to be of equal length):
X1 = [6, 8, 10]
X2 = [9, 11]

I'm trying to then create a vector
p = [p1, p2]

Where p1 is the probability of runner 1 winning. I assume each time of each runner has a chance of 1/N, where N is the number of samples for that runner. So, with this way I would get
p1 = 1/3 * 2/2 + 1/3 * 2/2 + 1/3 *1/2 = 5/6
The problem is if we put
X2 = [11, 12]

In that case, p1 would just be 1, which is a bit overestimated. So, I need a way to reduce these extreme predictions a bit. For example:
[0.5, 0.5] -> [0.5, 0.5] (keep the same for equals)
[0.75, 0.25] -> [0.72, 0.28] (give underdog a bit more)
[1.0, 0.0] -> [0.9, 0.1] (give underdog a lot more)

I know about softmax function, but it will offset the values too much for my liking.

You need a probability model for a racer's times.  It would take a lot of statistical work to come up with something realistic, but one simple and easy approach would be to try a normal distribution, using the data to fit the mean and variance.  So for the runner with times $[6, 8, 10]$ we would get a mean of $8$ and standard deviation $2$, while the runner with times $[9,11]$ would get mean $10$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{2}$.  The difference of their times (assuming independence) has mean $8 - 10 = -2$ with standard deviation $\sqrt{2^2 + \sqrt{2}^2} = \sqrt{6}$, so you might estimate the probability that the first runner's time is less than the second's in a given race as $\Phi(2/\sqrt{6}) \approx 0.7929$, where $\Phi$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution.
As I said, this is simple and easy, but it might not be very realistic.  One should expect the tails of the actual distributions to be thicker than normal on the high side (even a very good runner can suffer an injury or illness, causing a time much higher than usual) and thinner on the low side (the probability of me running a mile in less than $4$ minutes is essentially $0$).

Thank you for the answer. Maybe something like Student's t-distribution might help out with higher tails.
